# webcam worked yesterday, no more

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, ubuntu-10.04, webcam

Along with the rest of the world, I joined google plus right after invitations became available last night. I was able to use my webcam for their hangouts, now I cannot. When I checked lshw I can't find the webcam on the slot it was in last night.

Relevant system info: 
OS: ubuntu 10.04 
System model: Dell Inspiron 1525 lshw snippets:

```
       *-generic:2 UNCLAIMED
            description: System peripheral
            product: xD-Picture Card Controller
            vendor: Ricoh Co Ltd
            physical id: 9.3
            bus info: pci@0000:02:09.3
            version: 12
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
            configuration: latency=64
            resources: memory:fe3ff600-fe3ff6ff
       *-generic:3 UNCLAIMED
            product: Illegal Vendor ID
            vendor: Illegal Vendor ID
            physical id: 9.4
            bus info: pci@0000:02:09.4
            version: ff
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 66MHz
            capabilities: bus_master vga_palette cap_list
            configuration: latency=255 maxlatency=255 mingnt=255
            resources: memory:fe3ff700-fe3ff7ff
```

Comment: Well, *I* didn't join!